# Transition an element on a route change

Tags: vue.js, animation, transition, vue-router

I'm trying to transition this svg across the page when the route changes.
I've tried setting a watcher so when route path is 'comp1':'comp2' it should animate depending on the result.

The transitionName changes correctly, but the animation isn't firing...

Would love some help to know if this is possible and If so where I'm going wrong?

Thanks

```
<template>
<div class="background">
 <div class="background__content">
  <transition :name="transitionName"
  mode="out-in">
   <figure class="background__shape--primary">
    <svg viewBox="-5 -10 130 130">
     <path d="m0 0, 120 0, -60 100Z">
     </path>    
    </svg>           
   </figure>
  </transition>
 </div>
</div>
</template>


  <script>
    data(){
    return {
    transitionName: '',
       }
 },
    watch: {
       $route(to){
       let path = to.path;
       if(path === '/one'){
       this.transitionName = 'comp1';
       }
       else {
       this.transitionName = 'comp2';
      }
     }
      },
    </script>

<style>

    enter code here

.comp1-enter-active{
     transform: translate(20px, -50px);
     transition-duration: 0.3s;
     transition-property: transform;
     transition-timing-function: ease; 
     }   
.comp1-enter,
.comp1-leave-active{
    opacity: 0;



   transform: translate(20px, -50px);
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
    transition-property: transform;
    transition-timing-function: ease;
        }
.comp1-leave-active,
.comp1-enter {
    opacity: 0;
    animation-delay: 300ms;
    transform:translate(-26px, 80px);
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
    transition-property: transform;
    transition-timing-function: ease;
        }
.comp2-enter,
.comp2-leave-active{
     opacity: 0;
     transform: translate(50px, 20px);
     transition-duration: 0.3s;
     transition-property: transform;
     transition-timing-function: ease;
        }
.comp2-leave-active,
.comp2-enter {
     opacity: 0;
     animation-delay: 300ms;
     transform:translate(10px, 15px);
     transition-duration: 0.3s;
     transition-property: transform;
     transition-timing-function: ease;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: This seems like its a css problem could you show us your animation code.

Comment: If you scroll down it should be there

Comment: oh sorry i'm blind why are you using <transition> instead of just classes. Is it an package that you have?

Comment: I'm new to Vue, I thought that was best way of achieving this!

How would doing it with CSS classes look like?

Comment: Let me write up an answer real quick

Answer (score 0):

What you want to use is vue [class bindings](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html) with just a regular div.

```
<div :class="currentTranstion">Your SVG</div>


computed: {
    currentTransition: ()=>{
            return{
                comp1: router.currentRoute === one;
                comp2: router.currentRoute === two;
                
            }
        

    }

 }
```

This is not the most effcient way to do it but it is a breif idea

If you are cofused about css transtions [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp) explains it very well

Comment: Ahh thank you buddy. 

I'll try that in the morning and let you know how I get on.

I'll check out w3 but that makes sense